# Discord.js command cooldown

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm currently creating a discord bot. It has a custom economy in which you can earn coins with the work command. There should be a work cooldown of 2.5 minutes, but it doesn't work, so everyone can only use the command once each reboot. Does anyone see something I did wrong?
This is the code of the command:

```js
} else if (cmd == "work") {
  if (workers.has(msg.author.id)) {
    msg.channel.send("Don't work too much, or you could get a burnout!");
  } else {
    reward = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    works = work["works"];
    
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * works.length);
    
    msg.channel.send(works[i].replace("%price%", reward.toString()));
    
    if (econ.money[msg.author.id] === undefined) {
      econ.money[msg.author.id] = 200;
    }
    
    econ.money[msg.author.id] += reward;
    
    workers.add(msg.author.id);
    setTimeout(() => {
      
      workers.delete(msg.author.id);
      
    }, 150000);
}
```

It doesn't produce any errors.

Comment: What is `workers`

Comment: It's the set that keeps track of who worked recently.

Comment: Code for `workers` please

Comment: It's just const workers = new Set(); The rest is in the code of this command.